# FPU IA-32 SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception

Tags: assembly, fpu, x86

I have a problem with this code below. It is GAS asm syntax on IA-32 architecture. It generates arithmetic exception, after `fsqrt` instruction. `SetDouble` is `int` type of value `0x0200` and `input` is a float number. I'm compiling this with `-m32` flag using gcc. Can someone point where I made mistake.

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp
finit                   
fldcw SetDouble          
fld input               
fld input
fmulp
fld1                    
faddp                   
fsqrt                   
fld1
fxch                    
fsubp
fstp output
mov %ebp,%esp 
pop %ebp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the control word to 0x200 switches the FPU to double precision and unmasks all exceptions including the precision exception. As such for most inputs (probably everything except 0) the `fsqrt` will raise this exception and that's what you are seeing.

You can set the control word to 0x220 instead to mask the precision exception.