# fpu ia-32, floating point exception

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86, sigfpe

I'm learning ia-32 and everything was going fine on 32bit Ubuntu, but I switched to 64bit and started using the flag -m32 and now i can't use DIV anywhere, no matter the content of the registers, it gives me always Floating Point Exception... And I'm sure I'm not dividing by zero. I'm using gcc and gdb.

This is the closest question to my problem: [FPU IA-32 SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099872/fpu-ia-32-sigfpe-arithmetic-exception)

I tried to put the instructions fldcw with 0x220 but makes no difference.

My source code:

```
.section .text 

Division:
    .int 0x220

str: 
    .asciz "%d"

.global binario             # void binario(int)

binario:
    pushl %ebp          # prologo
    movl %esp,%ebp          # 

    finit
    fldcw Division

    pushl %ebx
    pushl %ecx
    pushl %edx

    movl 8(%ebp),%eax       # param x to eax

    cmpl $0,%eax            # compare x with 0
    je fim              # return recursive call

    movl $2,%ecx            # prepare division
    divl %ecx           # divide eax with 2

    movl $0,%ecx            # clean ecx
    movb %al,%cl            # put division result on cl

    pushl %ecx          # push x/2
    call binario            # recursive call
    add $8,%esp         # clean esp

    movl $0,%ecx            # clean ecx
    movb %ah,%cl            # put division rest on cl

    pushl %ecx          # push division rest
    pushl $str          # push string
    call printf         # call printf function
    addl $8,%esp            # clean esp

fim:

    pushl %edx
    pushl %ecx
    pushl %ebx

    movl %ebp,%esp          # epilogo
    popl %ebp               #
    ret
```

GDB log:

```
28      divl %ecx           # divide eax with 2
2: $ecx = 2
1: $eax = 33
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
binario () at ex08.s:28
28      divl %ecx           # divide eax with 2
2: $ecx = 2
1: $eax = 33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 for searching SO and using a debugger, -1 for not reading the instruction set reference ;)

The `div r/m32` variant that you are using divides the 64 bit quantity formed from `edx` (top 32 bits) and `eax` (low 32 bits). Furthermore, you also get this exception if your result is out of range. The problem is you are not zeroing `edx` so it has some random value which causes the whole division to overflow. You need to clear `edx` (zero-extend `eax`) before unsigned division, and sign-extend `eax` into `edx` before signed division.

PS: I hope you are not really using `div` to divide by `2`. To divide or multiply by powers of `2` you should use shifts.

Comment: Yes! It worked by zeroing edx. And yes, at first I used shifts but then I needed the rest of the division to convert an int into binary so I need %ah. I read too little of the instruction set T.T it's true. Shame on me.

Comment: `SHR` returns the shifted out bit in the carry flag (`CF`). Also you can get the LSB before the shift by masking. For binary conversion you can just use shift left to get the bits in the correct order without any recursion and such.